# не могу установить препроцессор Haml

Tags: haml

плохо знаком с командной строкой. пытаюсь установить Haml. с официального сайта копирую строчку и вставляю ее в командную соответственно. и вот что она мне отвечает:

C:\Users\renat>gem install haml

"gem" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

подскажите, что я делаю на так?

Comment: надо установить gem или если он уже установлен то прописать путь в переменные среды и перезагрузить консоль

Comment: спасибо. устанавливаю!!